# How do I make elements stand on top of each other when I resize the window?

Tags: html, css

When I make the window smaller, I noticed that elements overlap each other. What do I do, so when I make the window smaller, they will be displayed vertically?

I tried flex-wrap, and it worked with images. Not sure why it's not working this time.

```css
.align-center-1 ul{ 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="PSI.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="align-center-1">
      <ul>
        <li>HTML & CSS</li>
        <li>Javascript</li>
        <li>React</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use bootstrap grid system for mobile responsiveness

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MediaQuery` to make UI responsive and add breakpoint in CSS.

In this example i have added one breakpoint at 789px;

```css
.align-center-1 ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items:center;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media(max-width:789px)
{
  .align-center-1 ul
  {
    flex-direction:column;
     align-items:flex-start;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="align-center-1">
   <ul>
     <li>HTML & CSS</li>
     <li>Javascript</li>
     <li>React</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: View answer in full screen and try changing screen width. Please upvote and accept my answer, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried flex-wrap, and it worked with images. Not sure why it's not
> working this time.

By default `li` has a display property of `list-item`. It **does** wrap using the `flex-wrap` property you have mentioned but it does not consider the pseudo element `::marker` that your `li` generates. Thus, giving you the *illusion* that it does not wrap.

For this, I recommend using media queries to assign a minimum width to your `li` elements when certain breakpoints occur.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    li {
      min-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use display: inline-block value to solve this problem.
I hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="PSI.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .align-center-1 ul{
            display: inline-block;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            margin-right: 4rem;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <div class="align-center-1">
        <ul>
            <li>HTML & CSS</li>
            <li>Javascript</li>
            <li>React</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex-direction column for small screen sizes (change the media query with depends on your need).

```
@media(max-width:575.98px) {
  .align-center-1 ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```css
.align-center-1 ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media(max-width:575.98px) {
  .align-center-1 ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="PSI.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <div class="align-center-1">
    <ul>
      <li>HTML & CSS</li>
      <li>Javascript</li>
      <li>React</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) system, as it makes things like this quite easy to manage.

But if you just want them display vertically, then you can add a media query

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) { //use max-width as cutoff
  .align-center-1 ul{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually try flex-wrap.

```css
.align-center-1 ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  gap:3em;
}.align-center-1 ul li{
  margin-left:3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="PSI.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <div class="align-center-1">
    <ul>
      <li>HTML & CSS</li>
      <li>Javascript</li>
      <li>React</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</html>
```